# max-min calculation with more functions

Tags: mathematical-optimization, maximum

If I have max-min with two functions: 
$$\max_{x\in[0,1],y\in[0,1]} \min [f_1(x,y);f_2(x,y)]$$
I can find numerical solution with:

```
NMaximize[{Min[{f1[x, y], f2[x, y]}],  0 <= x <= 1 && 0 <= y <= 1}, {{x, 0,1}, {y, 0, 1}}]
```

Now I have complicated max-min with five functions:
$$\max_{x\in[0,1],y\in[0,1]} \min[\min [f_1(x,y);f_2(x,y)]+\min [f_3(x,y);f_4(x,y)];~f_5(x,y)]$$ 
I do not understand how I can extend the above code to solve the second problem numerically.

Can someone please guide me?

**Added**: For $f_1, f_3, f_5$ with different $c_i>0$ $$f_i(x,y)=(1-x) \log \left(1+c_i\left(\frac{1-y}{2-y}\right)\right)$$
and for $f_2,f_4$ with different $d_i>0$
$$f_i(x,y)=(1-x) \log \left(1+d_i\left(\frac{2 x}{1-x}+y\right) \right)$$
For simplicity, we may assume these constants as 1. 
This is an optimization problem, but before analyzing it, I want to see the behavior of the final answer by numerical search. I can do this with grid search but consumes time depends on grid size. I am just wondering above code can be extended to help for faster search.

Comment: Can you tell us what the functions are?

Comment: The approach you need will depend very strongly on the behaviour of your functions

Comment: I updated, and please have a look